# How to interrupt while uploading the file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, file, interrupt, form-data, uploading

I have a code in controller like below:

```
BASE.APP.post('/uploadFile/:request/:file', function(req, res, next) {

  var url = req.usersession.webipAddress;

  var path = 'uploads/' + req.params.file;

  var formData = new BASE.FormData();
  formData.append('fileNameUnique', req.params.file);
  formData.append('file', BASE.FS.createReadStream(path));
  //  console.log(formData);


  formData.submit(url + '/service/uploadFile/', function(err, response) {
    // console.log(response.statusCode);
    res.send(response.statusCode);

  });
});
```

I want to interrupt file upload if status == "cancel", is that
possible?

Comment: are you getting the status from the request?

Comment: What do you mean with if status == "cancel"?

Comment: What does formData.submit(url + '/service/uploadFile/' does?

Comment: So, I'd suggest you interrupt from the client if it is a user interrupt, However, if you want to interrupt a stream based upload, simply throw an error!.

Comment: It's not clear what the OP is asking us.

Comment: They're already sending the file to you, the TCP handshake is finished. You won't be able to get the client to stop uploading (unless you tell the client not to, over, say, websockets, and they stop uploading). You can ignore it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the value returned from `formData.submit` and use that as a handle to call `request.abort` on.

E.g.

```
BASE.APP.post('/uploadFile/:request/:file', function(req, res, next) {     

  var formData = new BASE.FormData();
  // ...

  var formSubmitRequest = formData.submit(url + '/service/uploadFile/', function(err, response) {
    res.send(response.statusCode);
  });

  statusChanger.on('status-change', function(status) {
    if (status === "cancel" && formSubmitRequest) {
      formSubmitRequest.abort();
      res.send(524);
    }
  });

}
```

From https://github.com/form-data/form-data:

> For more advanced request manipulations submit() method returns http.ClientRequest object

From https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_abort:

> request.abort()#
>
> Added in: v0.3.8
>
> Marks the request as aborting. Calling this will cause remaining data in the response to be dropped and the socket to be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If status == "cancel" try this:

```
req.pause()
res.status = 400;
res.end('Upload cancelled');
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the way your code works or your workflow. This is a generic soln that most likely will work. Add more code in the question if you want a more specific soln.

```
try {
    if (status === 'cancel') {
        throw new Error("Stopping file upload...");
    }
} catch (e) {
    res.end("the upload was cancelled because of error: " + e.toString());
}
```